# Responsive design on cell phones

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my code work on my Android phone but I don't get the right responsive design on my images. I want them to be smaller and also fit when turning the phone 45 degrees, on the horizontal side. Then the images don't fit at all.
How can I make the images smaller and also fit horizontally?

```
    <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (max-height:400px) {
  img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
  }
}
</style>

    <div class="slider">
  <a href=""><img class="mySlides" src="car.jpg" ></a> 
  <a href=""><img class="mySlides" src="train.jpg" ></a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to keep tweaking the size......

**Pro tip:**
Use vw and vh instead of %

```
width: 60vw;
height: 60vh;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this line messes it up:  and (max-width: 480px) and (max-height:400px). When removed, it looks better on my Android but then it also changes on my laptop display. Not sure how to get it perfect on both.

Comment: Try increasing the max-height as I think that your android may have more pixels than that......